# MDCFilter with Spring webflux using reactor netty and spring security oauth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux, reactor-netty

I have the following code, it's a MDCFilter.

```
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.BearerTokenAuthentication;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class NettyMDCFilter implements WebFilter {

    public static final String USER_AND_APPLICATION_KEY = "user";
    public static final String APPLICATION_KEY = "application";
    public static final String USERNAME_KEY = "username";

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return exchange.<OAuth2Authentication>getPrincipal()
            .doOnNext(this::logWithContext)
            .map(auth -> exchange)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(exchange))
            .flatMap(chain::filter)
            .doFinally(signalType -> removeMDCKeys());
    }

    private void logWithContext(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        MDC.put(USER_AND_APPLICATION_KEY, userKey(authentication));
        if (authentication.isClientOnly()) {
            MDC.put(APPLICATION_KEY, authentication.getName());
        } else {
            MDC.put(APPLICATION_KEY, authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId());
            MDC.put(USERNAME_KEY, authentication.getName());
        }
    }

    private void removeMDCKeys() {
        MDC.remove(USER_AND_APPLICATION_KEY);
        MDC.remove(USERNAME_KEY);
        MDC.remove(APPLICATION_KEY);
    }

    private String userKey(OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        if (authentication.isClientOnly()) {
            return authentication.getName();
        } else {
            return String.format("%s:%s", authentication.getOAuth2Request().getClientId(), authentication.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

In the previous implementation was implemented using the class [OAuth2Authentication](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/OAuth2Authentication.java), that belongs to the project the project [spring-security-oauth](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth), but this project now is under maintance mode , as you can see [here](https://spring.io/blog/2018/01/30/next-generation-oauth-2-0-support-with-spring-security#future-of-legacy-spring-security-oauth-project) . In my code, I want to check in the filter if the token belongs to a client application or to an user, but I don't have any idea about how could I do this in the new version of [spring-security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security) , even reading the documentation it's not clear for me what I should do, because there isn't a migration tutorial to migrate from spring-security-oauth2 project to the spring security project new version with built-in support to oauth2. I googled, but couldn't find a concrete tutorial to help me with this problem.

Comment: you cannot use MDC you have to use the Reactive context.  https://simonbasle.github.io/2018/02/contextual-logging-with-reactor-context-and-mdc/

Comment: You need to use Context - https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/context/Context.html